# List substraction with indices

Tags: java, list, loops, set-difference

Let's say I have a List A like that:

```
line value
0    Object0
1    Object1
2    Object2
3    Object3
4    Object4
5    Object5
```

Now, I've another List B containing `[0,2,3]` (only `Integer`) which basically contains the indices of objects I've already looked at.

I'd like to get the List C (it's the indices `[0,1,2,3,4,5]-[0,2,3]=[1,4,5]`):

```
line value
1    Object1
4    Object4
5    Object5
```

Btw : I need the original list to stay the same.

I could create the list of indices and then remove the B list to get the C list but is there an easy and efficient way to get directly the object?

Comment: Are the objects unique? If so you can just use HashSets

Comment: Yes all of them are unique

Comment: Wouldn't using HashSets be the same as Lists? Because my second list only contains indices (as in Integer) not the actual Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : (because I forget that you want the original list not changed) :
So a **ONE-LINE** operation is usefull :

```
//I recreate your scenario to test
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Object0"); list.add("Object1"); list.add("Object2");
list.add("Object3"); list.add("Object4"); list.add("Object5");
List<Integer> indexesToAvoid = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 3);
```

The principe is this : iterate over your objects, and keep the ones which index not appears into `indexesToAvoid`, and then collect them into a `new List` :

```
List<Object> resultList = list.stream()
        .filter(obj -> !indexesToAvoid .contains(list.indexOf(obj)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This solution has quadratic performance, more precisely the runtime is proportional to n*m, where n is size of List A and m is size of List B. Should be fine for small lists but could be a problem if lists are big.

Comment: We are in 2017 with ram counts in Go and disk with Go too, it's not this kind of operation which will slow down anything ^^

Comment: Precisely because of large ram counts the problem might arise, ratio between CPU speed and memory size is actually fairly constant. Efficiency is important and can not be dismissed by general comments like "oh it's year X". Also if runtime is not important, energy efficiency might be.

Answer (score 2):

it's easy to solve with streams, e.g.:

```
    List<Object> listC = IntStream.range(0, listA.size())
            .filter(n -> !listB.contains(n))
            .mapToObj(n -> listA.get(n))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`listA` and `listB` stays as is

Answer (score 1):

Generate a Set of indexes from 0 to size of the list exclusive and then remove indexes from another list and then populate resulting list by select objects by indexes from original list.

Using your example:

1. Generate `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` set
2. Subtract `[0,2,3]` from the set resulting in `[1,4,5]` set
3. For each index in `[1, 4, 5]` get object from source list and put in resulting list

Alternatively create a copy of original list and remove elements with `[0,2,3]` indexes from copy.

You might also want to consider changing data structure that holds `[0,2,3]` indexes and describe the problem in more general way, without postulating that `[0,2,3]` list of indexes has to be used, that could lead to more elegant and efficient solution.

Comment: Yes you're right, I just used these values to be easily understandable.
What do you mean by changing the data structure of my B List, would something else be better?

Comment: For example instead of keeping indexes can you just keep a set of objects themselves?